# Black Magic Pocket 6k Pro using either Sigma 18-35 or Sigma 24-70

Tags: zoom, wide-angle

hoping someone can help me: I've seen a lot of people choose the Sigma 18-35 over the 24-70 for the bmpcc 6k pro but can never find out why other than because of the crap factor. The majority of my content is interview style and some b-roll of the subject walking around (and occasionally some detail shots). Why is the 18-35 more often picked over the 24-70? I get it's a crop but 24 seems to be wide enough for most applications. In your opinion - would the 24-70 be better suited for the aforementioned situations or would the 18-35 be better? the in-camera stabilization seems attractive for some hand-help applications but not sure what to go with.

Essentially this: Most of my shots will be interview style with a mix of detail shots, extreme close-ups for emotion, and some wide to show the landscape (but extreme wides I always use my drone). The 24-70 has me 95% convinced but everyone else seems to go for 18-35 and I can't seem to find a reason to also go for it given my applications. Just want to make sure I'm getting the right gear before jumping in deeper.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What effective focal lengths do you use now?

Comment: The basics of crop factor are definitely on topic here, but you seem to have a good understanding of how crop factor affects angle of view, so that's not in question. Your situations and question are all in a videography context. The text for voting to close for that reason is: "This question is about video in a context that is not likely to be relevant to still photography." Thus, I believe this question is off-topic for Photography Stack Exchange. Can you edit your question to put the question more in a photographic context? Or if you like, we can migrate the question to [video.se].

Comment: My appologies! I didn't realize there was a video stack exchange! I'll close thsi question and move it over!

Answer (score 1):

I realized that there's a videography stack exchange and my question was better suited there. While editing my question - I realized something.

Of all my shoots, my 50mm has been used 98% of the time. The other 2% is to grab some establishing shots with the 24mm. The reason I barely grab establishing shots is because of the time to switch lenses as a solo videgrapher. Plus using a 50mm almost 100% of the time, it would be a waste to get a whole new lense for wide shots when I rarely do them.

TL;DR - I'm getting the 24-70 because majority of my videos to date have been on the 50mm and I don't see a point in getting a wider angle lense than what I currently have when I barely use it.